# jQuery qTip 1.0 - possible to set height / maxHeight?

Tags: jquery, qtip

I'm using qTip 1.0 and want to set the maxHeight, but I don't see this as being an option. Is there a way to accomplish this please? In this scenario, the tip would be stickied (ie, requires clicking on close to close) so that the user could also scroll down within the tip if the contents were longer than say 400px tall.

Any ideas please? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their documentation, no such option exists; however, you *can* set the `style` option which allows [Any valid CSS attribute/value pair](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#style). This merely sets CSS though, so you could see problems with browser limitations.  Perhaps you could use their `onRender()` or `onShow()` callback methods to manually add your own script to modify the height.

**Note** they also recommend switching to [qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/) which has a more robust API.